# Unable to configure printer in KDE

Tags: printing, kde

I am trying to change the configuration of my (network) printer in KDE. It is a bizhub 224e and I would like to configure it to print duplex. However, when I change the setting in Printers--> Configure --> Printer options, I am not asked for a password and the settings are reset to their pre-existing values after closing and reopening.

When I try changing the configuration from http://localhost:631/admin/ I get

```
Unauthorized
Enter your username and password or the root username and password to access this page. If you are using Kerberos authentication, make sure you have a valid Kerberos ticket.
```

But it is not clear to me where to enter my root credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CUPS via http://localhost:631 in Chrome has a bug that will not log into the CUPS admin pages in Ubuntu 18.04.  See bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1769893

Instead, use Firefox as the whole process will work fine there.